# Python (Django) how to assign a default value in case of error

Tags: python, django

Hey I'm using django in a project, using a POST method, the view in Django receives data, it works fine if the data is received but if no data is received I want to assign a default value instead of getting an error here is my code. I tried to use the if assignement but it doesn't work.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def getPacsPatients(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        PatientName = data["patientName"] if data["patientName"] else "*"
        #it works fine if data["patientName"] is present, but if not I get an error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read values from a dictionary with the `get()` function.

```
data.get(key, default_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

@brukidm gives the correct answer, however as your question implies you might be pretty new to Python, I'd also like to point out that in similar scenarios you can `try-except` around code, which is aligned with Python's [EAFP](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/) approach.

This would yield something like this:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def getPacsPatients(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try: 
            PatientName = data["patientName"]
        except KeyError: 
            PatientName = default_value
```

It executes the code in `try` block and if it runs across a `KeyError` executes an `except` block.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
try data["patientName"] :
    PatientName = data["patientName"]
except Exception as E:
    PatientName = "*"
```